# Oracle 11g - run windows batch file to run multiple sql files in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus, batch-file

I would like to use a single batch file to execute multiple sql in a sequence..
IE: sql2 script calls a table created by sql1 script.. etc..

here is the batch code I have so far.. 
it works to run a single sql file but I need it to run the first one and then then next..
thanks in advance.

```
    @ECHO OFF
echo.
echo.
SET /P uname=Username:
echo.
echo.
SET /P pass=Password:
echo.
echo.
SET /P mydatabase=Database:
echo.
echo.
set oracle_sid=ins

sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% @J:/A/scripts/_TABLES/Table1_.sql \n
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% @J:/A/scripts/_TABLES/Table2_.sql \n
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% @J:/A/scripts/_TABLES/Table3_.sql \n
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% @J:/A/scripts/_TABLES/Table4_.sql \n
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% @J:/A/scripts/_TABLES/Table5_.sql \n
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% @J:/A/scripts/_TABLES/Table6_.sql \n
sqlplus exit
pause
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

make a 'driver' sql script.

inside it would look similar to this:

```
@Table1_.sql
@Table2_.sql
@Table3_.sql
@Table4_.sql
```

then just call this one once from the OS

Comment: How could I pass parameters received in this SQL file (&1,&2 and &3 for example) to the four files launched ?

Comment: To run the 'driver' SQL script open a command-line and run with SQLPlus: "sqlplus username/password@sid @{path-to-driver-sql-script}\driver.sql"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can run them all together.

```
cat Table1_.sql > /tmp/temp.sql
cat Table1_.sql >> /tmp/temp.sql
cat Table1_.sql >> /tmp/temp.sql
sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@DOMAIN @/tmp/temp.sql
```