# Run sqlplus commands from multiple files with query logging or spool in Windows Batch File

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am quite new to batch scripting, and I am trying to run multiple sql files, which in turn may contain multiple sql DML/DDL queries from bat file. The output files must contain all the queries being executed and the query output. Unlike [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412040/sqlplus-command-line-with-windows-batch-file) ,  I don't have spool command inside my sql file, and I can not edit the input sql files. The following command works for me in ksh file (thanks to here-document):

```
$sqlplus  /nolog <<! >>$sqlLogs.lst
connect $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@${DBNAME}
set echo on timing on
spool ${SCRIPTRUNFILE_SPOOL}
select name from v\$database;
@${SCRIPTRUNFILE};
spool off
exit
!
```

I want the exact same in Windows bat file. I have tried [using ^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch). I can't do [combine all sql files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679626/oracle-11g-run-windows-batch-file-to-run-multiple-sql-files-in-sqlplus), as I need logging for each sql file into different file. My attempt at the bat file script is as follows and I have played around this much, and it fails with `spool command not recognized`. I also prefixed below commands with `sqlplus`, but still unable to achieve something like above ksh file:

```
sqlplus -s username/pwd@DBName >> sqlLogs.lst
set echo on timing on
spool %RUNFILENAME%.lst
@%RUNFILENAME% > %RUNFILENAME%.lst
select name from v\$database;
spool off
quit
```

Following logic executes my scripts but does not log the query being executed. Also, I don't want to connect twice to the database.

```
echo select name from v$database; | sqlplus -s username/pwd@DBName >> sqlLogs.lst
echo quit | sqlplus -s username/pwd@DBName @%SCRIPTRUNFILE%>> %SCRIPTRUNFILE_SPOOL%.lst
```

Can someone here please help to spool to a file where I can log the queries as well, while maintaining a single DB Connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your immediate SQL*Plus commands to your sqlplus via stdout, grouped together by Windows' `(` and `)` symbols...

```
(
    echo.set echo on timing on
    echo.spool %SCRIPTRUNFILE_SPOOL%
    echo.select name from v$database;
    echo.@%SCRIPTRUNFILE%
    echo.spool off
    echo.exit
) | sqlplus -s %USERNAME%/%PASSWORD%@%DBNAME% >> sqlLogs.lst
```

Comment: thanks. The above is able to log the output of the queries that I am running. It is  not logging the queries. I tried `echo.set serveroutput on`, but no luck. Can you help here?

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to do it by launching sqlplus with /nolog and then connecting inside as a bulk command. `(echo.connect username/pwd@dbname .... )|sqlplus /nolog`

Comment: @shrutisingh, the `set echo on` should do the exact trick you're asking for. I'm not sure why it doesn't in your case.